# I get a 503 response status whenever I try to make a POST request from my client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, client-server, axios

I recently created a server and deployed it to Heroku. It works fine in Postman and when testing out basic GET requests. But whenever I try to make POST request to it via Axios in my client, I am met with this error.

[image: Here is the error message I get.]

In my back-end server, I enabled cors so that it could make cross-domain requests. [Here, on lines 67 and 69, I set up cors before declaring my routes (click here to see the full 'app.js' file on my github.)](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jamrBackend/blob/master/app.js)

My register router works fine in Postman, and its response time is below 30 seconds, at 1877 milliseconds.

Interestingly, when I make a conditional GET requests to my API in my client, it works. [(The lines of code where I make aforementioned GET request are on line 222-258 here)](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jammrFrontFinal/blob/master/src/containers/Register.js)

[image]

In my client, the problem arises whenever I want to make a POST request in my client. Here is network response I get in the image below.

[image]

If I go to the response tab, it shows my POST request timing out at 30.1 seconds, despite the fact that the same API request was finished in 1.8 seconds in Postman.

Here is the code in particular where I am making the POST request in my `index_actions.js` file.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function register(fields) {

    console.log('below are the fields');

    console.log(fields);


    return function action(dispatch) {

        let objArrSkills = Object.keys(fields.form_skills);

        let skillsArr = objArrSkills.map(function (value) {

            if (fields.form_skills[value] === true && fields.form_skills[value] !== undefined) {

                return value;

            }

        });

        let objArrArts = Object.keys(fields.form_arts);

        let artsArr = objArrArts.map(function (value) {

            if (fields.form_arts[value] === true && fields.form_arts[value] !== undefined) {

                return value;

            }


        });

        console.log('artsArr is...' + artsArr);

        console.log('skillsArs is...' + skillsArr);


        const request = axios({

            method: 'post',

            url: "https://jammr-backend.herokuapp.com/register",

            data: {

                firstName: fields.form_first_name,

                lastName: fields.form_last_name,

                email: fields.form_email,

                password: fields.form_password,

                skills: skillsArr,

                iWantToMake: artsArr,

                street: fields.form_address,

                city: fields.form_city,

                provinceState: fields.form_province,

                gender: fields.form_gender,

                imLookingFor: ['Acting', 'Drawing', 'Music', 'Writing', 'Programming', 'Videography']


            },

            headers: {

                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'

            }


        });


        return request.then(response => {

                console.log('axios call ran! Below is response....');

                console.log(response);

                dispatch({

                    type: 'REGISTER',

                    payload: {

                        myId: response.data,

                        fields: fields,

                        skills: skillsArr,

                        iWantToMake: artsArr

                    }

                })


            },
            err => {

                if (err) throw err;

            })


    }
};
```

Everything works fine right up until I make the Axios to the `/register` route. The files pertaining to this issue are [here](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jammrFrontFinal/blob/master/src/containers/Register.js) and [here](https://github.com/tarekgabarin/jammrFrontFinal/blob/master/src/actions/index_actions.js).

UPDATE: I went into my `app.js` file to change the Cors configuration.I commented out `app.use(cors());` and `app.options('*', cors());` and replaced it with this.

```
    /// x-auth is a custom-header in my server-side code 


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,x-auth,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});


    /// After this line, I declare my routes.
```

However, now I am getting this error `Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: You see what the error message is?

Comment: Yes, it's in the console in my developer tools in Chrome

Comment: Are you sure your server endpoint is not crashing during the post request? I skimmed your backend code for that particulair endpoint and you are not dealing with any of the potential errors as far as I could see. Throwing errors or not catching rejected promises will cause your request to never return and eventually it will be timed out. You are saying that «the request» works with postman? Is that the same request? I.e the post to ‘/register’?

Comment: Yes, it works in Postman